# How to copy multiple files simultaneously using scp

Tags: linux, scp

I would like to copy multiple files simultaneously to speed up my process I currently used the follow

```
scp -r root@xxx.xxx.xx.xx:/var/www/example/example.example.com .
```

but it only copies one file at a time. I have a 100 Mbps fibre so I have the bandwidth available to really copy a lot at the same time, please help.

Comment: What is "100meg fibre"? 100mbit Ethernet? Or 10 GBit Ethernet?

Comment: script it!. Put a `&` in the end of each command to send it to the background or have a look at gnu parallel

Comment: @AaronDigulla Sorry I meant 100mbit Ethernet

Comment: @FredrikPihl I am not sure I am understanding what you mean, will you please elaborate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SSH is able to do so-called "multiplexing" - more connections over one (to one server). It can be one way to afford what you want. Look up keywords like "ControlMaster"

Second way is using more connections, then send every job at background:

```
for file in file1 file2 file3 ; do 
     scp $file server:/tmp/ & 
done
```

But, this is answer to your question - "How to copy multiple files simultaneously". For speed up, you can use weaker encryption (rc4 etc) and also don't forget, that the bottleneck can be your hard drive - because SCP don't implicitly limit transfer speed.

Last thing is using rsync - in some cases, it can be lot faster than scp...

Comment: S, what you are saying is 100% correct, but I am not only trying to access a few big files at a time. I am trying to download about 10 000 small images in total

Comment: Then the best way would be creating one archive (tar), maybe compressing it (gzip), then transfer and do inverse operation.

Comment: Thank you Mike, I think that is the best solution. Thank you so much!

Comment: Fastest way would be something like `ssh source.machine "tar czpf - /lot/of/data" | tar xzpf - -C /tmp`

Comment: @rogerdpack: Hi, look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22411932/setup-and-use-ssh-controlmaster-session-in-a-shell-script

Answer (score 9):

You can use background task with wait command. 
Wait command ensures that all the background tasks are completed before processing next line. i.e echo will be executed after scp for all three nodes are completed.

```
#!/bin/bash
scp -i anuruddha.pem myfile1.tar centos@192.168.30.79:/tmp &
scp -i anuruddha.pem myfile2.tar centos@192.168.30.80:/tmp &
scp -i anuruddha.pem myfile.tar centos@192.168.30.81:/tmp &

wait
echo "SCP completed"
```

Comment: This will just copy the same file multiple times

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure if this helps you, but I generally archive (compression is not required. just archiving is sufficient) file at the source, download it, extract them. This will speed up the process significantly.
Before archiving it took > 8 hours to download 1GB
After archiving it took < 8 minutes to do the same

Answer (score 3):

100mbit Ethernet is pretty slow, actually. You can expect 8 MiB/s in theory. In practice, you usually get between 4-6 MiB/s at best.

That said, you won't see a speed increase if you run multiple sessions in parallel. You can try it yourself, simply run two parallel SCP sessions copying two large files. My guess is that you won't see a noticeable speedup. The reasons for this are:

1. The slowest component on the network path between the two computers determines the max. speed.
2. Other people might be accessing example.com at the same time, reducing the bandwidth that it can give you
3. 100mbit Ethernet requires pretty big gaps between two consecutive network packets. GBit Ethernet is much better in this regard.

Solutions:

1. Compress the data before sending it over the wire
2. Use a tool like `rsync` (which uses SSH under the hood) to copy on the files which have changed since the last time you ran the command.
3. Creating a lot of small files takes a lot of time. Try to create an archive of all the files on the remote side and send that as a single archive.

The last suggestion can be done like this:

```
ssh root@xxx "cd /var/www/example ; tar cf - example.example.com" > example.com.tar
```

or with compression:

```
ssh root@xxx "cd /var/www/example ; tar czf - example.example.com" > example.com.tar.gz
```

Note: `bzip2` compresses better but slower. That's why I use `gzip` (`z`) for tasks like this.

Comment: In my scenario its not big files at all its around about 10 000 images, between 30-60kb each, So download at least 10 at a time wont slow down my connection if I am correct? I have not had one image or file from the server larger than 100kb. Also when I run two SCP session the download the same files and just override each other.

Comment: I know this is a fairly old question, but as @Philip suggests, the transfer speed has nothing to do with the bandwidth available, a simple tar will make things many, many times faster, the amount of data, and bandwidth used will be the same(ish), but the transfer speed will be great.

Answer (score 3):

You can use parallel-scp (AKA pscp): http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/parallel-scp.1.html

With this tool, you can copy a file (or files) to multiple hosts simultaneously.

Regards,

Comment: Provide brief details as answer along with Link

Answer (score 0):

If you specify multiple files scp will download them sequentially:

```
scp -r root@xxx.xxx.xx.xx:/var/www/example/file1 root@xxx.xxx.xx.xx:/var/www/example/file2 .
```

Alternatively, if you want the files to be downloaded in parallel, then use multiple invocations of scp, putting each in the background.

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
scp root@xxx.xxx.xx.xx:/var/www/example/file1 . &
scp root@xxx.xxx.xx.xx:/var/www/example/file2 . &
```